# Sort WooCommerce items by sku in cart, mini cart and orders

Tags: php, sorting, woocommerce, cart, sku

I am looking for a php snippet that sorts the woocommerce products according to sku in the mini cart/shopping cart, checkout page and thank you page.
The snippet below works well in the store but not for the rest.
Thank you in advance.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'am_woocommerce_catalog_orderby');
function am_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $args ) {
    $args['meta_key'] = '_sku';
    $args['orderby'] = '_sku';
    $args['order'] = 'asc'; 
    return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Sort WooCommerce cart items by vendor when using Dokan plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66108466/sort-woocommerce-cart-items-by-vendor-when-using-dokan-plugin/66108849#66108849), here is the way to sort cart items by SKU *(works for cart items, mini-cart items and order items)*:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_loaded_from_session', 'sort_cart_items_by_sku' );
function sort_cart_items_by_sku( $cart ) {
    $items_to_sort = $cart_contents = array(); // Initializing
    
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->cart_contents as $item_key => $item ) {
        $items_to_sort[$item_key] = $item['data']->get_sku();
    }
    asort($items_to_sort); // sort items by sku
    
    // Loop through sorted items key
    foreach ( $items_to_sort as $key => $sku ) {
        $cart_contents[$key] = $cart->cart_contents[$key];
    }
    WC()->cart->cart_contents = $cart_contents; // Set sorted items as cart contents
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Loic's advice is solid (and I have no reason to doubt any of his contributions), this looks like a simple job for `array_multisort()`.

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_loaded_from_session', 'sort_cart_items_by_sku');
function sort_cart_items_by_sku($cart) {
    $skus = [];    
    foreach ($cart->cart_contents as $item ) {
        $skus[] = $item['data']->get_sku();  // populate sorting array of sku values
    }
    array_multisort($skus, $cart->cart_contents); // sort cart_contents by sku values
    WC()->cart->cart_contents = $cart->cart_contents; // Set sorted cart contents
}
```

Mocked-up demo: https://3v4l.org/YE75c